# prevent ActiveX object always appear in the foreground (IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, activexobject

I'm writing a website to display the IP camera video.

And I use the code below to support IE:

```
<OBJECT ID="RtspVapgCtrl" style="postion: absolute; z-index:1;"  CLASSID="CLSID:45830FF9-D9E6-4f41-86ED-B266933D8E90"
CODEBASE="XXXXX" />
    <PARAM NAME="Url" VALUE="XXXXXXXXX"/>
    <PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="opaque"/>
    <PARAM NAME="Stretch" VALUE="true" />
    <PARAM NAME="VSize" VALUE="CMS" />
    <PARAM NAME="Language" VALUE="EN" />
    <PARAM NAME="ClientOptions" VALUE="68" />
    <PARAM NAME="ViewStream" VALUE="0" />
    <PARAM NAME="DisplayErrorMsg" VALUE="false" />
</OBJECT>
```

And I'm debugging on IE9.

The problem is, the video object always appear on top. 
But I need some div over it.

I've been searching for the answer and found it has been asked several times.
It can be perfectly solved by adding

```
<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="opaque"/>
```

to the object
and " wmode="opaque" " to the embed tag, then we can apply z-index on it.

But my case is different because I'm not using embed tag.
Mine is an RTSP video stream. Simply add "PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="opaque" " and set z-index doesn't solve the problem.

Hope someone would solve this. And sorry for my poor English.

Comment: BTW, I can't move the object to iframe because I just solved another bug by removing the iframe tag.

Comment: This is a [similar problem][1], also without a solution to date.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063405/how-to-keep-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-activex