# modal popup behind ActiveX

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have an MVC website with Knockout and jQuery included. I have as well an ActiveX implemented, called AlternaTIFF. On one page there should be a modal pop up opened, but somehow it is always behind the ActiveX (if I remove the ActiveX it is working fine). The modal pop up is opened with jQuery. I've tried already several things I found on the www, unfortunately none helped:

- play with z-index
- play with position
- tried several jQuery things: appendTo, moveToTop, change z-index after load
- have the modal outside any other divs
- add a wmode transparent parameter to the object

As I can't hide the ActiveX (e.g. with visibility), I can't solve the problem like this.

Do you have any other idea what to try?

That's my Alternatiff-object:

```
<object width="100%" height="800" classid="CLSID:106E49CF-797A-11D2-81A2-00E02C015623">
 <param name="src" value="@Url.Content("~/images/000002866_412097962.tif")">
 <embed width="100%" height="800" src="@Url.Content("~/images/000002866_412097962.tif")" type="image/tiff">
</object>
```

That's how my modal looks:

```
<div id="myModal" class="window" title="myTitle" data-bind="visible: ModalShow">
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="a" data-bind="checked: radioChoose" />text goes here</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="a" data-bind="checked: radioChoose" />text goes here</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="a" data-bind="checked: radioChoose" />text goes here</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: cancelRadio">Cancel</a> | 
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: saveRadio">Save</a>
</div>
```

That's how I open it:

```
                    self.ModalShow(true);
                    $("#myModal").dialog({
                        dialogClass: "no-close",
                        modal: true,
                        minWidth: 425,
                        resizable: false
                    });
```

Maybe I did something wrong, but I don't find where it is. As said without the ActiveX everything is fine and works as it should. The AlternaTIFF plugin is only working for IE and we has to run with IE8 (I'm using IE9 for developing).

Thanks already in advance and please let me know if you need more information

Thanks

Susanna

Comment: Was wondering if you ever found a solution to this, as i'm facing the same problem but cant seem to figure out a solution so far and there is really no other way around the problem.

Comment: Hi Q_ro, I spoke with the customer and explained him that I have to hide the activeX as the page won't work fine otherwise... And so I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the ActiveX inside an iframe. Sometimes this works, but by the looks of it if that doesn't work there are no more options. See [How to keep dropdown menu on top of ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063405/how-to-keep-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-activex)

Comment: Thanks BladeOrz, unfortunately it didn't work. But good to know that there are no other options to try. I think, I'll have to solve it completely different then.